# Reading multiple file locations and storing them in different arrays/hash in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a Directory txt file which contains file locations paths of different files categorized as Address files and Name Files

Directory FIle looks like

```
Names FIles
[
name file 1 location

name file 2 location
....
]

Address Files
[
address file1 location

address file2 location
....
]
```

I want to read this directory file and store all the name files and address files in name and address array/hash resp.

I am new to perl .So any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct would be to read in the file with `while`, and have two variables that serve as flags.  When you encounter the line `Names Files`, you set one flag to, say, 1.  Within the aforementioned `while` loop, you have an `if` statement that checks if the flag is set.  If it is, make it so subsequent lines (the name locations) are read into the array or hash of your choice.  When you encounter the `Address Files` line, you change the first flag back to 0, and set the second flag, sending those lines to your Address data structure.

**UPDATE:**

In general, it's a good idea to present what you've already tried - something to keep in mind for the future.
That said, we were all new to this at one point or another.  The code could look a bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($nameflag, $addressflag);
my %namehash;
my %addresshash;

while (<>) {

    chomp;

    # Setting the flags
    if ($_ eq 'Names Files') {
        $nameflag = 1;
        $addressflag = 0;
        next;
    } elsif ($_ eq 'Address Files') {
        $nameflag = 0;
        $addressflag = 1;
        next;
    } elsif (/^(\[|\])$/) {
        # Assuming you want to ignore those brackets
        next;
    }

    my @line = split;

    # Assuming your fields can be split on whitespace,
    # that the first field is the (unique) file name, and the
    # second field is the location

    if ($nameflag) {
        $namehash{$line[0]} = $line[1];
    } elsif ($addressflag) {
        $addresshash{$line[0]} = $line[1];
    }

}

# Then whatever you want to do with those hashes
```

You'd need a bit more to ignore those empty lines, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Hey Thanks Can you just show me the structure using flags...Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do seems to be

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my(@names, @addresses);

while( <DATA> ) {
  chomp;
  next if /^\s*\[*\s*$/;
  if( /Names FIles/ ... /]/ ) {
    push @names, $_;
    next
  }
  if( /Address Files/ ... /]/ ) {
    push @addresses, $_
  }
}

use DDP; p @names; p @addresses;

__DATA__
Names FIles
[
name file 1 location

name file 2 location
....
]

Address Files
[
address file1 location

address file2 location
....
]
```

Comment: Thanks guys That was very helpful. I used the while loop with flags to parse and push funtion to store the data in respective arrays